# Push project to branch created on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am very new to using Gitlab, I want to push a project to a branch I created from https://gitlab.com
So I needed help as to what steps I should take to pushing a completed project to the branch. Kindly get back to me with step by step ways to push a project to branch.

**Edits**
Here is what I tried to upload to a branch

```
git init
git remote add origin john_doe@hotmail.com:BluewhaleTeam/test-ki.git
git add .
git commit 'First commit'
git push -u origin Lukaku
```

When i do git remote add origin i get this Error error:

And several mariad of Errors. I just want to upload to the branch, thats all.

```
remote origin already exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the root directory of your project :

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:yournamespace/yourproject.git
git add .
git commit 'First commit'
git push -u origin master
```

Replace `yournamespace` and `yourproject` with your custom values.

Comment: git push -u origin master where master is the name of the Branch i am pushing to correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, master is the default branch.

Comment: Pls see Edits , See what i did , did not work in my case i get some Errors

Comment: Then just run the 3 last lines.